# CSS Sprite button (span in anchor?)

Tags: jquery, css, inline-styles

So I've got a link, it can be anything.

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page" class="readMore">
    <span>Read More</span>
<a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page" class="readMore">
    <span>You should REALLY click this button!</span>
</a>
```

I would like to use CSS sprites, which I'm familiar with. However - since this text can vary soooo much, I can't really use 2 or 3 iterations of a "100px wide" button. So I found a way to split the background with an A and SPAN. it works great!.............Unless you hover over the very right side, where only the right corner activates the hover state. I've set up a fiddle here to show you.

http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/qkQQy/

Hover over the center and it works beautifully. Hover over the very right side, and it doesn't looks quite as sexy.

Is there a simple way to remedy this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another selector to style the `span` based on its parent being hovered:

```
.readMore:hover span,
.readMore span:hover {
    background-position: 0 -48px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qkQQy/1/).

Now, if either the `span` itself is hovered, or just the parent `a.readMore` element is hovered over, it should look identical.

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something stupidly simple... Haha! I'll chalk it up to "being Friday". But thanks! I'll accept it in 10 minutes :)

Comment: No problem at all, you're very welcome and I'm glad to have helped! Plus, it's Friday here, too. And I've done sillier things today. Some days, there's just not enough coffee in the world... =)

Comment: the second selector is redundant, the '.readMore:hover span' will always be triggered when the span:hover is triggered. Just to be exact...

Comment: @PeterVR: this is true; but I chose to leave it there (albeit I left no comment about that, see? Not enough coffee...) to show where it should go, and, perhaps, why. Sigh.

Comment: Well, this Friday is a real doozy, isn't it :P